# How do I turn a string of numbers into a list on Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out how many numbers in a text file are larger than 0.1.
The text file has 1001 last names and numbers in the following format:

```
Doe 5
Anderson 0.3
Smith 6
```

I figured out how to separate the numbers but i'm having trouble converting my string of numbers into a list so that I can then compare them to 0.1

Here is what I have so far:

```
    infile = open('last.txt')
    lines = infile.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        items = line.split()
        nums = (items[1])
```

also, once I have my list, how do I go about comparing it to 0.1?

Answer (score 4):

Supposing `lines` is a list of strings, and each of them consists of exactly one number and nothing more.

```
result = sum(1 if float(x) > 0.1 else 0 for x in lines)
```

Another very similar way to do the same:

```
result = sum(float(x) > 0.1 for x in lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

From your description, and code snippet, you seem to have a file that has a space separated name an number like so:

```
Name1 0.5
Name2 7
Name3 11
```

In order to get a sum of how many number are greater than 0.1, you can do the following:

```
result = sum(float(line.split()[1]) > 0.1 for line in lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers tell you how to count the occurrences which are greater than 0.1, but you may want to have the numbers in a list so that they can be used for other purposes.  To do that, you need a small modification to your code:

```
with open('last.txt', 'r') as infile:
    lines = infile.readlines()

nums = []
for line in lines:
    items = line.split()
    nums.append(float(items[1]))
```

This gives you a list `nums` of all of the numbers from your file.  Note that I have also used the Python context manager (invoked with `with`) to open the file which ensures that it is closed properly once you are no longer using it.

Now you can still count the occurrences of values larger than 0.1 in `nums`:

```
sum(1 if x > 0.1 else 0 for x in nums)
```